# Setting Different Fees For Sign Up and Renewal In Civicrm

Tags: civimember

The organization am configuring Civicrm for has different fees for Membership Sign up and renewal.

How can i configure Civicrm such that when Members are signing up they pay a particular fee but when they have to renew they pay a diffferent fee.

I have experimented with  price sets but this merely shows price sets on both signup and renewal pages as options. But this is not how i want it to work.

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar situation and use a separate contribution page for renewals.

The menu link for renewals takes them to an intermediate Drupal page that is only visible if they are logged in, and only members (or ex-members) have a login. On that intermediate page is the link to the renewing CiviCRM contribution form.

This isn't perfect but works for our case where new memberships include a book, renewing memberships don't and the difference in the fee is only $5.  If a lapsed member renews rather than rejoins we aren't fussed, we just don't send them the book.

Comment: Thanks JoAnne. I have thought of this option but now am trying to experiment with Cividiscount. Will update you how that goes.

Comment: Yes, pease do answer your own question if you get Cividiscount to work as that will help others who have this same problem in the future.  (I will stick with separate pages as we also have different financial acccounts for new and renewing members.)